# QR code scan to Flutter web. How to access data from QR code before running main?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-qrcode

Hello Everyone: I am in a further situation. I want to build a app with flutter web. User scans the QR code from his camera app (Android or Iphone) and then the link to my website will be returned. Now that QR code can store more info than just a link. How can I access that QR code data from a QR code that was not taken in flutter framework and to get that data in flutter. For example the additional data that the QR code could store is a location of it. Coordinates for example. How can I access those cordinates when opening the flutter web app.

Answer (score 1):

Use static [base](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/base.html) property in `Uri`

> When running in a browser, this is the current URL of the current page (from window.location.href).